# Is it possible to limit how long an Oracle SQL query runs for and return the results it gathered in the time limit?

Tags: sql, oracle

In a similar fashion to how

```sql
select * from mytable where rownum <= 1000;
```

will give me the first 1000 rows of results of a query, is there a way to

```sql
select * from mytable where runtime <= 1000;
```

which would return the results obtained in the first 1000 <time units> of running the query?

Comment: What do you mean "what is the use case?"?!?!? The use case is I want to retrieve some results of my query in a given amount of time...  You might as well ask what's the use case for having `rownum <= n`, you could just run the whole query and ignore the results except the first `n` rows!

Comment: A top N type of query often has a valid business case. eg, give me the top 1000 sales people by amount sold. I cannot imagine a valid business case where the results are based on how long the query takes. In many cases, the result set is determined as a "whole".

Answer (score 2):

Oracle does not support this, at least not in an easy sense like your example.

[One blog](https://blog.pythian.com/oracle-limiting-query-runtime-without-killing-the-session/) I found was able to limit the execution time of users in a certain resource group that they made.  They created a special group for said users, and then they defined a resource plan that they called `LIMIT_EXEC_TIME` for that user.  Their code is as follows for reference:

```
set serverout on size 5555
--
-- first remove an existing active plan
ALTER SYSTEM SET RESOURCE_MANAGER_PLAN ='';
--
-- delete any existing plan or group
-- we have to create a pending area first
exec dbms_resource_manager.clear_pending_area();
exec dbms_resource_manager.create_pending_area();
exec dbms_resource_manager.DELETE_PLAN ('LIMIT_EXEC_TIME');
exec dbms_resource_manager.DELETE_CONSUMER_GROUP ('GROUP_WITH_LIMITED_EXEC_TIME');
exec DBMS_RESOURCE_MANAGER.VALIDATE_PENDING_AREA;

exec DBMS_RESOURCE_MANAGER.SUBMIT_PENDING_AREA();
begin
  dbms_resource_manager.create_pending_area();
  --
  -- we need a consumer group that maps to the desired oracle user:
  dbms_resource_manager.create_consumer_group(
    CONSUMER_GROUP=>'GROUP_WITH_LIMITED_EXEC_TIME',
    COMMENT=>'This is the consumer group that has limited execution time per statement'
    );
  dbms_resource_manager.set_consumer_group_mapping(
    attribute => DBMS_RESOURCE_MANAGER.ORACLE_USER,
    value => 'PYTHIAN',
    consumer_group =>'GROUP_WITH_LIMITED_EXEC_TIME'
  );

  -- and we need a resource plan:
  dbms_resource_manager.create_plan(
    PLAN=> 'LIMIT_EXEC_TIME',
    COMMENT=>'Kill statement after exceeding total execution time'
  );

  -- now let's create a plan directive for that special user group
  -- the plan will cancel the current SQL if it runs for more than 120 sec
  dbms_resource_manager.create_plan_directive(
    PLAN=> 'LIMIT_EXEC_TIME',
    GROUP_OR_SUBPLAN=>'GROUP_WITH_LIMITED_EXEC_TIME',
    COMMENT=>'Kill statement after exceeding total execution time',
    SWITCH_GROUP=>'CANCEL_SQL',
    SWITCH_TIME=>15,
    SWITCH_ESTIMATE=>false
  );

  dbms_resource_manager.create_plan_directive(
    PLAN=> 'LIMIT_EXEC_TIME',
    GROUP_OR_SUBPLAN=>'OTHER_GROUPS',
    COMMENT=>'leave others alone',
    CPU_P1=>100
  );

  DBMS_RESOURCE_MANAGER.VALIDATE_PENDING_AREA;

  DBMS_RESOURCE_MANAGER.SUBMIT_PENDING_AREA();

end;
/

exec dbms_resource_manager_privs.grant_switch_consumer_group('PYTHIAN','GROUP_WITH_LIMITED_EXEC_TIME',false);

exec dbms_resource_manager.set_initial_consumer_group('PYTHIAN','GROUP_WITH_LIMITED_EXEC_TIME');

select * from DBA_RSRC_CONSUMER_GROUPS;
select * from DBA_RSRC_GROUP_MAPPINGS;
select * from DBA_RSRC_PLANS;
select * from DBA_RSRC_PLAN_DIRECTIVES;

-- to enable it:
ALTER SYSTEM SET RESOURCE_MANAGER_PLAN ='LIMIT_EXEC_TIME';

SELECT se.sid sess_id, co.name consumer_group,
 se.state, se.consumed_cpu_time cpu_time, se.cpu_wait_time, se.queued_time
 FROM v$rsrc_session_info se, v$rsrc_consumer_group co
 WHERE se.current_consumer_group_id = co.id;

select username,resource_CONSUMER_GROUP,count(*) from v$session group by username,resource_CONSUMER_GROUP;
```

**Partial Results**

Queries can return partial results but the query will also throw exception "ORA-00040: active time limit exceeded - call aborted" that must be ignored by the client.

This can be simulated with a function that does a lot of CPU work:

```
create or replace function sleep_cpu return number authid current_user is
    v_loop number := 0;
begin
    for i in 1 .. 10000000 loop
        v_loop := v_loop + 1;
    end loop;
    
    return v_loop;
end;
/
```

SQL*Plus can demonstrate a client able to read partial results:

```
SQL> set timing on
SQL> select sleep_cpu()
  2  from dual
  3  connect by level <= 100;

SLEEP_CPU()
-----------
   10000000
   10000000
   10000000
   10000000
   10000000
   10000000
   10000000
   10000000
   10000000
   10000000
   10000000
   10000000
   10000000
   10000000
   10000000
ERROR:
ORA-00040: active time limit exceeded - call aborted


15 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:08.52
SQL>
```

Note the Elapsed time in this example is 8 seconds.  I set the timeout to 5 seconds, this demonstrates that it's hard to get good precision.

**CPU Time, Not Elapsed Time**

Resource manager only counts CPU time, not elapsed time.  This is despite what the documentation says.  One of the comments in the Pythian article suggests this behavior can be changed with an `ALTER SYSTEM SET EVENT = '10720 trace name context forever, level 16384' scope=spfile;` (and a restart), but that didn't work for me.

For example, create this function:

```
create or replace function sleep_no_cpu return number authid current_user is
begin
    execute immediate 'begin dbms_lock.sleep(1); end;';
    return 1;
end;
/
```

This SELECT will run for the whole 100 seconds because it's not using 100 seconds of CPU.

```
select sleep_cpu()
from dual
connect by level <= 100;
```

Comment: I saw this page as well, and decided it looked like way more effort than it was worth, haha.  I also wasn't quite sure if this actually returns the partial results, do you know if it will?

Comment: @Apollys the way the blog is worded makes me think it doesn't return anything.  They don't say exactly how that aspect works.

Comment: @Apollys For what it's worth, the article says "to limit the query time."

Comment: I don't think applying a resource plan does what Apollys wants. Because if the query exceeds the granted resources it's aborted. Whatever result was accumulated up to then is discarded and the query results in an error