# Is it possible to set the time-out for a procedure after one minute when it is called in PLSQL

Tags: plsql, timeoutexception

The procedure is in a package. When a procedure is called the client function got hanged. So they are asking to set a timeout for the API. Is it possible?

Comment: AFAIK, it is possible to do in JDBC, for example. Anyway, the the best way is to implement this on the client-side.

Comment: No, you cannot set a timeout within the procedure.  The call is synchronous.

Comment: I think you would be better advised to investigate why the called procedure is hanging and **fix that** . For starters, is it waiting on something? Or deadlocked? Or just written inefficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.  However, I believe you should be able to accomplish what you are looking for, though I have never done it and do not have time to put together a proof of concept right now.  Here is an outline of what you would need to do:

1) See this answer for a trick (kludge?) to get Oracle's resource manager to limit by execution time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43532330/5174436

2) Modify the resource plan consumer group mapping to only apply to resource limit to a given `MODULE_NAME`.

3) Set the given module name in your procedure via `DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE`.

I offer no guarantees it will work.  It is merely what I would try if I were faced with your need.

Actually, that is not true..  what I would *really* do if I were faced with your need is figure out why the procedure is "hanging" and fix it.